# How do I position my Bitmap on the canvas using a Matrix?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm implementing a pinching and dragging thing and I'm confused as to how to get the image that I'm affecting to move to it's dragged to location (the scaling is working).

So, in the past I would position the image thusly...

```
canvas.drawBitmap(img, x,y, paint);
```

but now that I'm using a matrix I don't see what function in it gets the image over to where I want it to be.

Could someone post a short code snippet of what one needs to do to get the image to move away from 0,0?

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [postTranslate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#postTranslate%28float,%20float%29) on your scaling matrix:

```
scaleMatrix.postTranslate(x, y);
canvas.drawBitmap(img, scaleMatrix, paint);
```

Comment: I was trying that... it didn't want to work until you said something about it... thanks! :)